# How to change the window.resource style setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, setter

```
 <Window.Resources >
        <Style x:Name="stylepropery" x:Key="BaseContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MyFillBrush}"  />
        </Style>

        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}" />

     <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

which is applying common font color to all the labels and textboxes now i want to change the  color of font from code behind but some how its not applying 
i just want to change setter ***propery value***

```
 Setter setter = new Setter(ContentControl.ForegroundProperty, dt.Rows[0]["value"]);
 Style style = this.FindResource("BaseContentControlStyle") as Style;
 style.Setters.Add(setter);
```

I have used this but not succedd

Comment: Its not possible to have two `Setter` for a `Property` in a `Style`.. and also make sure that the `Style's` `Setter` are not sealed...

Comment: So if i want to apply color to all control using codebehind its not possible? is it so?

Comment: If that Style are not sealed, then you can remove the old setter for foreground and add a new setter.. it will works...

Comment: how to do that i am not getting it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this may help you

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ContentControl));
```

style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ContentControl.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
Resources["BaseContentControlStyle"] = style;

Answer (score 0):

```
            var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
            var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(dt.Rows[0]["value"].ToString());
            Style st = this.Resources["BaseContentControlStyle"] as Style;
            Random r = new Random();
            this.Resources["MyFillBrush"] = (new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(dt.Rows[0]["value"].ToString()));
```

After lots of googling i have found the solution i am adding this solution for the future refrence users so they don't have to search many things :)